# Python lxml find text efficiently

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

Using python lxml I want to test if a XML document contains EXPERIMENT_TYPE, and if it exists, extract the <VALUE>.

Example:

```
<EXPERIMENT_SET>
  <EXPERIMENT center_name="BCCA" alias="Experiment-pass_2.0">
    <TITLE>WGBS (whole genome bisulfite sequencing) analysis of SomeSampleA (library: SomeLibraryA).</TITLE>
    <STUDY_REF accession="SomeStudy" refcenter="BCCA"/>
    <EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTES>
      <EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE><TAG>EXPERIMENT_TYPE</TAG><VALUE>DNA Methylation</VALUE></EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE>
      <EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE><TAG>EXPERIMENT_ONTOLOGY_URI</TAG><VALUE>http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/OBI_0001863</VALUE></EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE>
      <EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE><TAG>EXPERIMENT_ONTOLOGY_CURIE</TAG><VALUE>obi:0001863</VALUE></EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE>
      <EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE><TAG>MOLECULE</TAG><VALUE>genomic DNA</VALUE></EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE>
    </EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTES>
  </EXPERIMENT>
</EXPERIMENT_SET>
```

Is there a faster way than iterating through all elements?

```
    all = etree.findall('EXPERIMENT/EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTES/EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE/TAG')
    
    for e in all:
        if e.text == 'EXPERIMENT_TYPE':
            print("Found")
```

That attempt is also getting messy when I want to extract the <VALUE>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferably you do this with XPath which is bound to be incredibly fast. My sugestion (tested and working). It will return a (possible empty) list of VALUE elements from which you can extra the `text`.

PS: do not use "special" words such as `all` as variable names. Bad practice and may lead to unexpected bugs.

```py
import lxml.etree as ET
from lxml.etree import Element
from typing import List

xml_str = """
<EXPERIMENT_SET>
  <EXPERIMENT center_name="BCCA" alias="Experiment-pass_2.0">
    <TITLE>WGBS (whole genome bisulfite sequencing) analysis of SomeSampleA (library: SomeLibraryA).</TITLE>
    <STUDY_REF accession="SomeStudy" refcenter="BCCA"/>
    <EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTES>
      <EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE><TAG>EXPERIMENT_TYPE</TAG><VALUE>DNA Methylation</VALUE></EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE>
      <EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE><TAG>EXPERIMENT_ONTOLOGY_URI</TAG><VALUE>http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/OBI_0001863</VALUE></EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE>
      <EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE><TAG>EXPERIMENT_ONTOLOGY_CURIE</TAG><VALUE>obi:0001863</VALUE></EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE>
      <EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE><TAG>MOLECULE</TAG><VALUE>genomic DNA</VALUE></EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE>
    </EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTES>
  </EXPERIMENT>
</EXPERIMENT_SET>
"""


tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xml_str))
vals: List[Element] = tree.xpath(".//EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE/TAG[text()='EXPERIMENT_TYPE']/following-sibling::VALUE")
print(vals[0].text)
# DNA Methylation
```

An alternative XPath declaration was provided below by Michael Kay, which is identical to the answer by Martin Honnen.

```xml
.//EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE[TAG='EXPERIMENT_TYPE']/VALUE
```

Comment: Personally I would rewrite `.//EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE/TAG[text()='EXPERIMENT_TYPE']/following-sibling::VALUE"` as `.//EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE[TAG='EXPERIMENT_TYPE']/VALUE`

Comment: @MichaelKay That's probably a better solution indeed. I'll add it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of XPath it seems you simply want to select the VALUE element based on the TAG element with e.g. `/EXPERIMENT_SET/EXPERIMENT/EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTES/EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE[TAG = 'EXPERIMENT_TYPE']/VALUE`.

I think with Python and lxml people often use a text node selection with e.g. `/EXPERIMENT_SET/EXPERIMENT/EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTES/EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE[TAG = 'EXPERIMENT_TYPE']/VALUE/text()` as then the xpath function returns that as a Python string.

Answer (score 0):

Using `findall` is the natural way to do it. I suggest the following code to find the VALUEs:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.parse('toto.xml').getroot()

all = root.findall('EXPERIMENT/EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTES/EXPERIMENT_ATTRIBUTE/TAG')
for e in all:
    if e.text == 'EXPERIMENT_TYPE':
        v = e.getparent().find('VALUE')
        if v is not None:
            print(f'Found val="{v.text}"')
```

This outputs:

```
Found val="DNA Methylation"
```